# Ubuntu login loop after NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

GPU: NVIDIA geforce 1080 Ti
OS: fresh install of 16.04 64bit, with upgrades applied
Symptom: The desktop won’t load after password entry. I am redirected to login screen. 
Installation method: I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo install nvidia-396
```

Then I rebooted, and the problem appeared.

I checked /var/log/Xorg.1.log and found the lines “Warning, couldn’t open module nvidia” and “Failed to load module nvidia (module does not exist,0)”

and then finally a Segfault later, preceded by some errors about Nouveau

Comment: How did you install `nvidia-driver-396` into `16.04`?  That is for `18.04` and the graphics drivers ppa should have detected that.  You can still install 396.26 into 16.04 but its name is `nvidia-396`.

Comment: @Terrance I installed `nvidia-396`, edited question

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS so that the NVIDIA drivers will load?

Comment: @Terrance Secure Boot was already disabled. I fixed the issue and added some information in an answer

Comment: Ah, it's a tower / desktop computer.  +1 for good troubleshooting.  =)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved now, although I tried a few things and can't isolate or rule out any of them from contributing to the resolution. Here's what I tried:

- In my `xorg.conf` file under the GPU Device configuration, I added the field `BusID PCI:1:0:0`, as my GPU was attached this PCI slot. It seems that `nvidia-config` might have failed to add this information. I'm not sure if it's always necessary.
- I looked for the object files of the drivers with `locate`, and ensured that there were in locatable directories. I don't recall making any changes or symlinking anything.
- I removed some `.conf` files for NVIDIA, it seemed these might have been taking precedence over the primary `xorg.conf` file.
- I plugged my monitor into the output of the GPU card, instead of into the motherboard.